# MicroLab K310 headset. Mic not detected

Tags: microphone, headset

Today I bought aforementioned headset and discovered that microphone on this headset is not being detected by anything. This headset got 1 3.5mm connector which I tried connecting to front panel (green) and it's being detected as headphones only. I'm using Win 7 x64. I tried updating my sound card drives and it didn't help in any way.

What can I do to make Win detect mic on this headset too?

Comment: Do you have only one input there on your computer, or 2?

Comment: On front panel? Both pink and green one.

Comment: I don't know "pink" and "green" but if there are 2 inputs, the mic and headphones are probably not accessible with one jack in. One will be for the 'phones and the other for the mic.

Comment: If this is the case, please let me know and I will make it an answer.

Comment: Yeah, pink is mic input, green is speakers input.

Comment: When you say speaker input, that makes no sense. Speakers don't put in. Speakers take out. From the sounds of things, you will need 'phones with 2 jacks. Therefore your new headphones will not work the way you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a splitter, such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008OB2NHA) from amazon.

My guess is your cable is a single jack with 4 'bands', [ground, audio out L & R & mic in]. You need to split it to just a TRS [ground, out L & R] which goes in the green socket & a separate mic TS jack [ground & mic] which goes in the pink socket
[the picture shows both as TRS, but that's not vital for the mic plug.]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it was totally this.